# Dojo widget to display a dgrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I have been working to create a simple templated widget that contains a dgrid using dojo. Here is [my code in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/juBEow7wV59mnj2VvVdR?p=preview):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
</head>
<body class="claro">
  <div id="myContainer"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
      async: true,
      parseOnLoad: true,
      packages: [{
        name: 'dgrid',
        location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v0.3.16'
      }, {
        name: 'myApp',
        location: window.location.href.replace(/\/$/, "")
      }]
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/array", "myApp/SimpleTemplatedGridWidget", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, arrayUtil, MyWidget) {
      var widget = new MyWidget.placeAt(myContainer);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

SimpleTemplatedGridWidget.js

```
define([
     "dijit/registry",
     "dojo/_base/declare",
     "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
     "dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry",
     "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
     "dojo/text!./SimpleTemplate.html"
],
function (registry, declare, Grid, DijitRegistry, _TemplatedMixin, template) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {

        data : [
            { first: 'Bob', last: 'Barker', age: 89 },
            { first: 'Vanna', last: 'White', age: 55 },
            { first: 'Pat', last: 'Sajak', age: 65 }
        ],

        columns : {
            first: 'First Name',
            last: 'Last Name',
            age: 'Age'
        },

        CustomGrid : declare([Grid, DijitRegistry]),

        postCreate: function() {
            myGrid = new CustomGrid({
                columns: columns,
                idProperty: "id"
            }, this.AttachGrid);
            myGrid.renderArray(data);
            myGrid.startup();
        }       
    });
});
```

SimpleTemplate.html

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point='AttachGrid'></div>
```

I am seeing errors I can't decipher both locally and at plunker. What might I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have serious errors in your code, some are javascript basics, others of dojo.

**Your code**

```
var widget = new MyWidget.placeAt(myContainer);
```

**Should be**

```
var widget = new MyWidget().placeAt(myContainer);
```

Also, `myContainer` is confusing, to broad, I recommend using `dojo/dom` that you already included

```
var widget = new MyWidget().placeAt(dom.byId('myContainer'));
```

Now, about your widget, your widget is extending `_WidgetBase` but it is not included, so

```
define([
     "dijit/registry",
     "dojo/_base/declare",
     "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
     "dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry",
     "dijit/_WidgetBase", //You are missing this module
     "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
     "dojo/text!./SimpleTemplate.html"
],
function (
    registry, 
    declare, 
    Grid, 
    DijitRegistry, 
    _WidgetBase, //Also include it here
    _TemplatedMixin, 
    template
    ) {
```

When extending `_TemplatedMixin` we need to define the `templateString` that should be a template loaded with `dojo/text!....` or an static template, in your case

```
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: template, //need to add
```

Now, your `postCreate` function is referencing a lot of undefined variables, that looking to your code, i'm assuming you want to get the properties of the widget itself, so

```
        postCreate: function() {
            myGrid = new this.CustomGrid({
                columns: this.columns,
                idProperty: "id"
            }, this.AttachGrid);
            myGrid.renderArray(this.data);
            myGrid.startup();
        }
```

note that i've added `this.` in the front of `columns`, `data` and `CustomGrid`;

This changes solve the most of your issues, just remaining one complaining about an `already registered widget` that I solved by removing the `DijitRegistry` module as I don't know what it does and is use to.

I recommend you some links:

[Creating Template-based Widgets](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/templated/index.html)
[Understanding _WidgetBase](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/understanding_widgetbase/index.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much Castro! Did you happen to make those edits and make it work? Unfortunately I was trying to organize the plunks and I ended up deleting the code without noticing your answer. I recreated the code and made the changes you suggested and edited the link in my question. But it is still giving me an empty page and I am getting 404 errors for

Comment: the 404 you are getting is because `dgrid` need some packages as `put-selector/put` and `xstyle/has-class` and is trying to fetch them from the wrong location, either update to the latest `dgrid` version that is `v1.1.0`, or you will need to adjust your `dojoConfig` so you can load this modules from the correct location

Comment: Check out [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jRz36GkKbluxvQ6bjldr?p=preview) it is your code but just with the `dgrid` version set to `v1.1.0` and it works ok :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see the data, but it doesn't ook like a regular dgrid (it normally looks like this: http://jspreadsheets.com/images/libraries/dgrid/dgrid-pagination-example.png). It appears to be formatted as regular text. I tried on different browsers and it doesn't work. What might be missing?

Comment: Are you including the `dgrid` styles?, this is the url if you are using the CDN `cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0/css/dgrid.css`

Comment: OK, finally, you'd notice that the header and the contents are overlapping. Is there a way to fix it as well?

Comment: No, i don't, but, if you have any further issues, please, feel free to open a new question.